# Does not send message using XMPP

Tags: android, connection, xmpp

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button reply;
    EditText say; 
    String username;
    private ListView listView;
   XMPPConnection connection=HomeScreen.connection;

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.chatbos_listview);
      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
      Intent i=getIntent();
      username=i.getStringExtra("username");
      say=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reply);
      reply=(Button)findViewById(R.id.replybtn);    
      reply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          String text = say.getText().toString();

          @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              Message msg = new Message(username, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);              
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.sendPacket(msg);
                    //messages.add(text);
                    //setListAdapter();
                }
                System.out.println(connection);

            }
        });
     }
```

Basically its a chat app. I have created the connection in start-up activity and in this activity i am getting connection from start-up activity and sending the data to a user. But it doesn't work. Please guide me.

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: i can't send messages

Comment: @selvin it doesn't show any exception.I successfully got the connection but i don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code inside the onclick method 
String text = say.getText().toString();

Comment: just a small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

before sending message , you have to create chat with the other user to whom you want to send message read here : http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/messaging.html

also send message in Asyntask not on main UI , otherwise your app will get crash.

Comment: i added the user. i got the username from another activity.
username=i.getStringExtra("username");

Comment: have you implement packet listener.?

Comment: yes.and also i confirmed the connection and user name value by printing them on console. it works fine.But still got sending problem.